# How to make jquery accordion not to use "height" required by its content until is actually shown?

Tags: jquery-ui, accordion

It's hard to explain in a single line, my problem is that I need to use accordion and I thought that when none of its items are expanded, it would use the space only required by headers.

This is not true, but I need a functionality where accordion will use the height that is actually using. So if it's using 30px because the content of the current header requires only 30, it doesn't force my body to grow a lot.

If I change the header to one that require 1000px height, then the accordion should use ~1000px forcing my body to grow

How is possible to reach this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check out the documentation, specifically http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#collapsible?

Comment: Damn I didn't notice the "No Autoheight" thing: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#no-auto-height If you post it as an answer I can mark it.

Comment: Well, I didn't direct you to towards "No Autoheight" - you figured that out yourself. Go ahead and answer it yourself to close this up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered myself following Grilse suggestion: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#no-auto-height

autoHeight to false will do the trick